Visual Studio Code Source Control: remove 'Reopen closed repository'
Just deleted a repository which was still active in VSC Source Control.
Now Source Control doesn't get that I deleted the repo. So I closed it, in the hope of being able to connect with a new repo, but no. When opening Source Control I'm greeted with this message:
"Reopen closed repository"
What can I do to just connect a normal git repo again?

Solved it by backing up the data and then just deleting the folder and creating it again...
If anyone knows a better solution lmk
